# Is this the same tomcat maven plugin?

Tags: tomcat, maven, maven-3, tomcat7

Are these the same plugin as seem to accomplish the same task ?

http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/deployment.html

http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html

Update : almost certainly the same plugin  -
Taken from http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0-beta-1/Apache Tomcat Maven Plugin

This is the new home for the Tomcat Maven Plugin (previously hosted at Codehaus).

Which one should I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should now use the one from Tomcat.

[tomcat-maven-plugin](http://mojohaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/index.html) also makes it clear it has moved.